# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Could not find stored procedure 'Core.SetContextInfo'.' I am getting this error no idea why

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, sqlclient

[image]

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Could not find stored procedure 'Core.SetContextInfo'.'

This procedure is present in my database all connection look fine but not sure why I am getting this error. I am not able to access application and when I debug I found this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get this error, it is probably because of not using correct name of database or schema before the name of stored procedure. I suggest you use fullname of stored procedure with the name of database and schema (if you have one) before your stored procedure name.

Comment: Could not find server '*****' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.'

Comment: I added server name but now it gives this error. Looks like I am close

Comment: As I said before, you need to find the correct database name and add it to the name of your procedure. Your error shows that the name you used, is wrong again.

Comment: thanks it worked guys

Comment: I realized im using wrong DB Name in my connectionString as shown below               <add name="PrimaryConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=**Wrong_DB_Name**;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />